# Linq con sub consulta para obtener una lista

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework-core

queria pedirles ayuda, estoy teniendo problemas para formular la query linq, la cosa es asi, tengo un metodo que recibe array de enteros ( usuariosId) necesito que devolver una lista de usuariosclientes (tabla intermedia entre usuario y cliente) que a la vez de contener los id del array, los id de los clientes sean iguales.

```
Usuario {
   int Id
}
 UsuarioCliente {
    int Id
    int UsuarioId
    int ClienteId
}
   public IEnumerable<UsuarioCliente> GetPendientes(int[] usuarios)
     {
      var clientesusuarios = Context.Set<UsuarioCliente>().Where(x => usuarios.Contains(x.UsuarioId));
     }
```

(hasta ahi llegue, solo obtengo todos los clientesusuarios que tienen id usuarios igual al array)

desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Qué significa que "los id de los clientes sean iguales" ? Que la propiedad "ClienteId" sea igual a la "UsuarioId" ?

Comment: En caso de ser así, entiendo sería algo así:
Context.Set<UsuarioCliente>().Where(x => usuarios.Contains(x.UsuarioId) && x.UsuarioId == x.ClienteId);

Comment: "los id de los clientes sean iguales" con eso me refieron a que despues de filtrar por los usuariosId, necesito obtener de esa lista los que tengan el mismo cliente Id (yo supongo que con una subconsulta pero no me estaria saliendo

Answer (score 0):

Lo podes resolver recorriendo tu vector de id y hacer la consulta, la que coincida se agrega.

```
 public IEnumerable<UsuarioCliente> GetPendientes(int[] usuarios)
 {
    List<UsuarioCliente> clientesusuarios = new List<UsuarioCliente>();

    foreach (int id in usuarios)
    {
       var cliente = Context.Set<UsuarioCliente>().Where(x => x.UsuarioId.Contains(id)).FirstOrDefault();

       if (cliente != null)
         {
           clientesusuarios.Add(cliente);
         } 
    }

 }
```

Comment: Pero el .Where(x => usuarios.Contains(x.UsuarioId))  ya te va a estar trayendo sólo los ítems que coincidan. Nunca va a traerte instancias NULLs, a lo sumo una lista vacía si es que no encontró ningún registro que coincida. Es innecesario el foreach y agregarlos a la lista. O no los estoy entendiendo bien yo..

Comment: el contains, es un metodo sobre el string al que se lo pasas, podes hacer constains para evaluar que la cadena string tenga las letras str.